# Why do keyboard functions/bluetooth not work after Win 10 only install?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, bootcamp, windows, bluetooth

Recently had Windows 10 installed on my Macbook Pro but the keyboard keys (except the power button, oddly) does not work. Neither does Bluetooth. The drivers all seemed to properly install with bootcamp software and the setup exe. Also tried to repair/redo the setup for the Apple drivers but no luck. 
The latest bootcamp windows software somehow didnt have the drivers or something?? 
No idea..
Ive got pics of it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjlCX.jpg

Comment: To add.. everything else works just great! Haven't activiated windows yet but theres no way that's the issue.

Comment: Did you try Apple Software Update?

Comment: Yeah i've tried it. So the software for bootcamp is updated and all. Thanks. Idk what to try next, i saw this program called Brigadier that pulls Apple software/drivers...Surely there's a way.

Comment: Brigadier should produce the same Windows Support Software that can be downloaded using the Boot Camp Assistant.

Comment: Alright, it worked. It installed both the keyboard and bluetooth driver unlike the Boot Camp Tools for whatever reason.